# Gráfico de interação utilizando ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

tudo bem? estou tentando realizar um gráfico de interação entre os sujeitos (Variável S) sendo estes sujeitos coloridos em 5 cores (que são os grupos (variável G), porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> Error in select(., Peso, Tempo, S) : unused arguments (Peso, Tempo, S)

```
dados$G  <- factor(dados$G)
dados$S  <- factor(dados$S)
dados$S1 <- factor(dados$S1)
str(dados)
attach(dados)

library(tidyverse)

interaction <- dados %>%
  select(Peso, Tempo, S) %>%
  group_by(S, Tempo) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(Peso))

x11()

ggplot(interaction, aes(x=Tempo, y=Average, colour=G, group=S)) + 
  ggtitle("Evolução do peso no tempo para cada individuo em grupos") +   
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir esse erro. O erro (evidente) é que `G` não é uma variável de `interaction` e portanto não pode ser `colour = G`. Basta mudar para `select(Peso, Tempo, G, S)` e `group_by(G, S, Tempo)` e corre tudo bem.

Comment: `interaction` é uma função R base, talvez queira mudar para, por exemplo, `interact`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como disse em comentário à pergunta, O erro é que `G` não é uma variável do dataframe `interaction` e portanto não pode ser `colour = G`. Basta mudar para `select(Peso, Tempo, S, G)` e `group_by(S, G, Tempo)` e corre tudo bem.

Note ainda que mudei o nome de `interaction`, uma função do R base, para `interact`. O código usado e o gráfico são os seguintes. O dispositivo `x11()` foi desativado para poder exportar o gráfico traçado nesse dispositivo, algo que o RStudio não permite.

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read.csv("dadosnovo.csv")

interact <- dados %>%
  select(Peso, Tempo, S, G) %>%
  group_by(S, G, Tempo) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(Peso))

#x11()

ggplot(interact, aes(x=Tempo, y=Average, colour=G, group=S)) + 
  ggtitle("Evolução do peso no tempo para cada individuo em grupos") +   
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Rui!! !!

Answer (score 0):

Pela mensagem de erro acredito que o R não está reconhecendo a função.

Isto pode ocorrer porque alguns pacotes possuem funções similares.
Uma maneira de declarar explicitamente uma função é colocar o nome da biblioteca seguida por dois pontos duas vezes.

Tente usar `dplyr::select(Peso, Tempo, S)` e me diga se o erro persiste.

Comment: obrigado Lucca!

Comment: @BrenoGabriel caso a resposta esteja correta você pode marcá-la como certa para que outros usuários também possam encontrá-la. Abraço!